# MS Access Multiple Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many, relational-database

I have one table "Liability" which is currently providing the available coverage amounts in a dropdown box.  It has the following fields:

```
[CoverageAmountID]
[CoverageAmount]
[Cost]
[StateID]
[ProductID]
[CompanyID]
```

There are many coverage amounts, companies, states & products.

A complicated query currently pulls the correct Coverage Amount options.  My question is if I need to split this up and how?

I have no relationships for this now but there are State, Product & Company Tables.

Do I create junction table with the CoverageAmountID, StateID, ProductID & CompanyID as the primary key?

Is there a better way to handle this with multiple m:m junction tables?

I'm struggling with how this data should be structured.  The attached picture shows what I have in the table currently.

[image: Liability Table]

Comment: Are those multi-value fields I see? I NEVER use them. Or are those actually CSV strings? Not sure which is worse. Strict data normalization calls for junction tables. It is a balancing act between normalization and ease of data entry/output - "Normalize until it hurts, Denormalize until it works".

Comment: I failed to mention that I have 13 other tables in my database that are structured this way.  I would like to nomalize everything but not sure how to structure the data since they all have four tables involved with many records from each.

Comment: To get rid of the multi-value fields you need a State table with StateID's and a Company table with CompanyId's. Then use a junction table with just CoverageAmountID and StateID fields (you should make those both primary keys). So CoverageAmountID 1 will have 3 entries in your junction table.  And one junction table with CoverageAmountID and CompanyID (again both should be primary keys) so CoverageAmountID 2 will have 2 entries in this junction table.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery,  Apart from eliminating the Multi-value fields is there a better way to normalize this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalizing the liability database:

- Instead of using many values in one field, use intermediary tables for **many to many relationships**
- Better use **numbers for keys**, using text in relationships will be challenging.
- If you have one product per coverage then you have a **one to many relationship** in which case you can use a direct relationship from CoverageTbl to ProductTbl
- Yes, you need separate tables with **own primary Keys** for ProductTbl, StateTbl & CompanyTbl
- Attached is a tentative design showing relationships, Note all IDs are of type number, Codes are of type text(5)
  [database design/relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR8jX.jpg)

Comment: Thank you Morris!  This was the answer I was looking for.  I was hoping to avoid something like this but I guess if it's the correct way to go then I'll bite the bullet.   I have so many tables to do this to.   ARGG!!